# Bibtex Not Generating Correct Reference AIP Style

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I am using the AIP.bst style file that is the first result from a Google search. I'm trying to cite a book, but the book is not appearing in AIP style. In the references section, it is appearing as,

> M. E. Peskin and D. V. Schroeder, An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory, CRC
> Press, Boca Raton, 2019.

However, according to the AIP style guide, https://guides.lib.vt.edu/find/citation-style-manuals/aip, it should look like this,

> M. E. Peskin and D. V. Schroeder, An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory, (CRC
> Press, Boca Raton, 2019).

I have no idea how to edit the AIP.bst file; it seems like gibberish. All that I want to do is have the parentheses surround the publisher and year like it does in the style guide. Can anyone make a suggestion about what to do?

Comment: Did you, by any chance, download the bst file from the [bibtex.com](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-phy-bstyles-aip/) site? If so, please be advised that bibtex.com has no known recognized connection to BibTeX (the program that's distributed with many TeX distributions) or to Oren Patashnik (the author of BibTeX). The advice one may find on bibtex.com is sometimes usable, and sometimes wrong. If you want to argue with the maintainers of the bibtex.com site that their bst file is faulty, please take the discussion straight to them.

Comment: It would appear to be the case that the aip.bst file distributed by bibtex.com dates back to 1992 [!] and thus may be based on the fourth edition of the AIP formatting guidelines (which were published around 1990). In contrast, the guidelines you found on the University of Vermont Library site are based on the 199, i.e., *fifth*, edition of the AIP guidelines. Editing an old, undocumented bst file is often both difficult and unsucessful. I would suggest that you check if the formatted output produced by `aipnum4-1.bst` and/or `aipnum4-2.bst` meets the current set of AIP guidelines.

Comment: @Mico to be fair, the old physics bst styles can be also found on CTAN https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/phy-bstyles?lang=en and they are not clearly marked as obsolete.  And if you don't already know about revtex, finding it on CTAN is a bit harder.

Answer (score 1):

`aip.bst` is not the correct bibtex style file.

If you are submitting to an AIP journal, you should use `revtex` which loads the correct bibtex file. AIP has [even published templates for Overleaf](https://publishing.aip.org/resources/researchers/author-instructions/#latex).

If you, for some reason, just want to use the AIP bibliography styles, the one that revtex loads is either `aipnum4-2.bst` or `aipnum4-1.bst` (depending whether you are basing it on `revtex4.1` or `revtex4.2`). Both can be found on CTAN.

Comment: I am not submitting to an AIP journal, I'm writing my dissertation. My university has supplied their own thesis template that I'm using so I can't use the revtex document type.

Comment: If your university supplies the file `aip.bst`, then take the discussion to whoever is in charge of distributing the faulty file.